# Using Stokes' theorem for evaluation of a line integral

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Let C be the curve of intersection of the plane $x+y+z=1$ and the cylinder $x^2 +y^2=4$, oriented counterclockwise when viewed from above. What is the value of the line integral $\oint\limits_{C} xy^2dx +x^2ydy+z^3dz$?

I have parametrised the equations for the curve of intersection to give: $x=2cos(u)$, $y=2sin(y)$ and $z=1-2cos(u)-2sin(u)$. What do I do next?

Comment: You do not have to parametrize the curve if you want to use Stoke's theorem. You have to compute the rotor $\nabla\times F$ and, eventually, parametrize the surface you choose (probably the piece of plane limited by the curve that you parametrize). Could you check the first component of the vector field? It's not usual to write the constant terms at the end, that's why I asked.

Comment: @PQH Sorry I mistyped I have corrected it to $xy^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note in this specific case, your vector field is gradient of scalar field $F$

where $F = \frac{x^2y^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{4}$.

$(xy^2, x^2y, z^3) = \nabla(\frac{x^2y^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{4})$

As it is in conservative vector field, the line integral over a closed loop will be zero.

But if it was not, please note that you are interested in intersection curve of $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $x + y + z = 1$. The unit normal vector to the plane will be $(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}).$

You then need to find curl of the vector field $\nabla \times F$ normal to the surface (do a dot product with unit normal) and then do the double integral.

Answer (score 0):

The rotor is $(0,0,0)$ so you get, by Stoke's theorem, that the line integral is 0.